# Forward to a friend - custom profile center URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, custom-profile

i was wondering if it is possible to insert a custom link in the forward to a friend feature.

I explain you below the steps of this process and where I would like to change.

1. A contact receives an email with ftaf link ‎inside.
2. The contact clicks on the ftaf button and he is redirected to the standard web form ‎where he can insert few email addresses and a text message in order to forward the email
3. These new (or already existing) contacts receive the email from their Friend with a message "If you want to Subscribe to this newsletter please click here"
4. If the contact clicks on the subscribe link, he will redirect to the standard profile center
5. The contact fills the fields in the profile center page and click "update". In this way i could see the new subscriber in the all subscriber list.

My question is concerning to the possibility‎ to substitute the link at the third step. Can i change the URL so that the contact will redirect to a custom profile center (created using landing page)?

Answer (score 3):

**I'd advise against doing any kind of FTAF.**

It's a terrible user-experience.  Plus, unless you have some sort of bulletproof double opt-in and suppression system, you'll likely end up marketing to someone who never consented. That is bad.

Every time someone on one of our client teams wants to build a custom FTAF feature, we get about 10 hours into the design and then dump it.

I'm sorry.  I know this didn't answer your question.